# Tmux send-prefix not works in iTerm2 integration mode

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, iterm2

in mac os high sierra, i installed tmux using homebrew.
when i run tmux command simply in iterm2 it works great! i can use ^b for send-prefix and it works but when i run the tmux with -CC option then the ^b prefix not works!

Comment: This looks related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063195/iterm-2-not-honoring-key-bindings-declared-in-tmux-conf?rq=1 Basically, the point of the iTerm2 + tmux integration is to remove the need to use the ^b prefix. I know, this annoys me too. I actually like the prefix.